# brackets inside matrix / matrices inside a matrix

Tags: matrices, brackets, alignment

I would like to make something that looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how to get the brackets inside the matrix to line up in the right spots. I don't need them to be red; I just added that to emphasize what I want.

Here is what I used to make this (sans red brackets):

```
\begin{bmatrix}
I_p \\
& \ddots \\
&& I_p \\
& I_p \\
&& \ddots \\
&&& I_p \\
&&& \vdots & \ddots \\
&&& \ddots & \vdots \\
&&&& I_p \\
&&&&& \ddots \\
&&&&&& I_p
\end{bmatrix}
```

EDIT: See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476227/brackets-around-blkarray-are-too-big) followup question for the solution I went with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `blkarray`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    \begin{block}{[ccc]cccc}
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{c[ccc]ccc}
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
    & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \begin{block}{cccc[ccc]}
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty good! Do you know how to adjust it so that the spacing at the top and the bottom is more even? That is the only thing I don't like about this solution as it is.

Comment: I fixed it. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476227/brackets-around-blkarray-are-too-big) post.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{NiceArray}{ccccccc}[margin]
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
      & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
      & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
  \CodeAfter
     \SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-3}]
     \SubMatrix[{4-2}{6-4}]
     \SubMatrix[{9-5}{11-7}]
     \SubMatrix[{1-1}{11-7}][extra-height=1mm,xshift=1mm]
  \end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]