# Brackets around blkarray are too big

Tags: arrays, brackets, blkarray

This is a followup to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476099/brackets-inside-matrix-matrices-inside-a-matrix/476102#476102) question.

MWE (given by Henri Menke in the linked post):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    \begin{block}{[ccc]cccc}
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{c[ccc]ccc}
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
    & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \begin{block}{cccc[ccc]}
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

This produces this: [image]

This is almost what I want, except the brackets produced by `\left[` and `\right` are too long on the bottom. I feel like there must be a way to do this exclusively in a blockarray, but the documentation for the package is not extensive enough that it has quickly led me to such a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blkarray` is so weird....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\addtolength\textwidth{25pt}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    \begin{block}{[ccc]cccc}
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{c[ccc]ccc}
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
    & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \begin{block}{cccc[ccc]}
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
  \right]
+
 \left[
  \begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
    \begin{block}{[ccc]cccc}
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{c[ccc]ccc}
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
    & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \begin{block}{cccc[ccc]}
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
    \end{block}
    \BAnoalign{\vspace{-20pt}}
  \end{blockarray}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should contact the author of `blkarray` about this. ;)

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

Without modification of \verb|\delimiterfactor|.
%
\[ \left[\begin{NiceArray}{ccccccc}[margin]
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
    & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
    & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
\CodeAfter 
\SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-3}]
\SubMatrix[{4-2}{6-4}]
\SubMatrix[{9-5}{11-7}]
\end{NiceArray}\right]\]
%
With \verb|\delimiterfactor=1050| and \verb|\delimiterfactor=901| back in the \verb|\CodeAfter|.
%
\[\delimiterfactor=1050
   \left[\begin{NiceArray}{ccccccc}[margin]
      I_p \\
      & \ddots \\
      & & I_p \\
      & I_p \\
      & & \ddots \\
      & & & I_p \\
    & & & \vdots & \ddots \\
    & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
      & & & & I_p \\
      & & & & & \ddots \\
      & & & & & & I_p \\
\CodeAfter
\delimiterfactor=901 % default value
\SubMatrix[{1-1}{3-3}]
\SubMatrix[{4-2}{6-4}]
\SubMatrix[{9-5}{11-7}]
\end{NiceArray}\right]\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]